# How to use read.xport transfer the label

Tags: r, sas

I am importing a SAS dataset test.xpt into **R**, but the label is not transferred.

```
library("SASxport")
here <- getwd()
setwd('E:/')
test <- lookup.xport("test.xpt")
```

output:

```
> test

$DATA

$DATA$headpad

[1] 25440


$DATA$type

...

$DATA$width

...
...
...

$DATA$label
...
```

There is label. But when I use read.xport, the label is gone.

```
test.data <- read.xport("eos91fin.xpt")
label(test.data)
```

All of them are blank " ". What should I do?

Comment: I'm not an R expert, but I thought the label() function was to _set_ a label.  Describe() is usually used to show labels, no?

Comment: I used describe, but there was still no labels.

Comment: You did not include any output that showed the labels to be anything other than empty character elements.